# Conditionally resolve named implementation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

Unity allows you to name different implementations of the same interface and then resolve them by name:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

// register
container.Register<IFish, OneFish>("One");
container.Register<IFish, TwoFish>("Two");

// resolve
var twoFish = container.Resolve("Two");
```

Now assume I have a class that depends on IFish and implements ITank:

```
class Tank : ITank
{
   public Tank(IFish fish) {...}
}
```

How can I resolve ITank and specify which implementation of IFish to get?

This doesn't work:

```
container.Register<ITank, Tank>();

var tank = container.Resolve<ITank>("One");
```

This works:

```
var fish = container.Resolve<IFish>("One");

var tank = container.Resolve<Tank>(new DependencyOverride(typeof(IFish), fish);
```

but it only handles simple cases (such as in this example) not the general case where there may be many implementations named "One". What I want is to be able to tell to Unity:

*"When resolving use implementations named "One", if no such implementation is register fall back to the unnamed implementation"*

Is there a custom resolver that can be plugged into Unity with this behavior?

Comment: did you get an answer to your query here? I am facing a similar problem statement.

Comment: Nope sorry. Eventually I may write an extension for Unity, but the simple solution I outlined is enough for my needs right now. I'll update if I do.

Answer (score 4):

You could you the InjectionFactory of Unity to inject a named instance.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

// register
container.Register<IFish, OneFish>("One");
container.Register<IFish, TwoFish>("Two");

container.RegisterType<ITank,Tank>(new InjectionFactory(c=>c.Resolve<IFish>("One")));
```

If you now resolve an instance of type Tank, an instance of OneFish is injected to your Tank.

To handle your case that you want to inject a default implemenation of IFish you can change InjectionFactory to the following

```
new InjectionFactory(c=>{
  if (c.IsRegistered<IFish>("One")) {
    c.Resolve<IFish>("One");
  }
  else {
    c.Resolve<IFish>("Two");
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the idea is not to use a strict on registration configuration. Think about a system with several modes, most of the classes are instantiated the same way, but a few differ between the modes: in the "production" mode data is I/Oed from the main database and errors are logged and the "ad-hoc" mode the data is I/Oed from XML files and no logging occurs. I want to be able to tell Unity: resolve "production" or resolve "ad-hoc" simultaneously at run time, and I want to share the common registration. I'm hoping someone knows of an existing Unity plugin for this.

Comment: I thought this might be a workable solution for me but it's throwing exceptions trying to cast IFish to ITank?