# Unity: The current type is an interface and cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

Got below code to start with

```
public interface IDataContextAsync : IDataContext
{
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}

public partial class DB1Context : DataContext{ }

public partial class DB2Context : DataContext{ }
```

Below is the UnityConfig file. Note: I am using Nuget bootstrapper for ASP.Net MVC and below is my UnityConfig file

```
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {           
        container
            .RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, DB1Context>("DB1Context", new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
            //.RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, DB2Context>("DB2Context", new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
            .RegisterType<IRepositoryProvider, RepositoryProvider>(
                new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
                new InjectionConstructor(new object[] {new RepositoryFactories()})
            )
            .
            .
            .
            .
    }
```

And I am getting below error:

> The current type, Repository.Pattern.DataContext.IDataContextAsync, is
>   an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?

Understand that this named instances is not working with my UnityConfig.
Any idea guys?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you trying to resolve?

Comment: does DB1Context implement IDataContextAsync... via DataContext?

Comment: can you show us the code that tries to resolve this? is it in a service locator or just done manually?  When IDataContextAsync is being resolved it thinks you have not set up a corresponding configuration for it, maybe because of the way it's getting called.

Comment: does the error go away when you do this: .RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, DB1Context>()

Comment: @Backs, I am trying to resolve inside the constructor of the mvc controller. What's the best place to do so? I am using generic repository pattern for EF6 at https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

Comment: @CRice Yeah the error goes away after I remove the named registerType. Something is not quiet working with named instance. Probably as Backs suggested, it might have to do with the place where I am trying to resolve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your service locator that is doing the resolving (after your constructor asks for IDataContextAsync) is probably trying to resolve like this:

```
Current.Resolve<IDataContextAsync>()
```

when it needs to resolve like this

```
Current.Resolve<IDataContextAsync>("DB1Context");
```

and there wouldn't be any extra logic built into it for it to know that.

If you want to conditionally resolve you could use an injection factory:

```
   public static class Factory
   {
        public static IDataContextAsync GetDataContext()
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 10)
            {
                return new DB1Context();
            }
            else
            {
                return new DB2Context();
            }
        }
    }
```

..and register IDataContextAsync like this:

```
Current.RegisterType<IDataContextAsync>(new InjectionFactory(c => Factory.GetDataContext()));
```

Since it takes a delegate you don't necessarily need the static class / method and could do it inline.

Comment: where according to you I should put the code which tries to resolve DB1Context?

Comment: what about the answer by Jehof if you want it to work the same for each type that uses it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171135/conditionally-resolve-named-implementation-in-unity

Comment: Problem solved with the InjetionFactory way. Named instance anyways is not clean too. Thanks heaps mate.